# DB column name generation problem (missing column) when OneToMany is in the abstract class

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

**Situation:** Our application has been working properly with all the OneToMany associations, with the names, columns. We decided out of nowhere that we want our entity objects to change names just by adding DAO at the end. Object -> ObjectDAO.

**What we did:** We changed object names as planned. Then every entity got its **@Table(name = "object")** annotation, but now we are running into problems on our join tables. The names of columns are now generated badly - not using the given table's name. We want the column names to remain `object_id` instead of `objectdao_id` but @Table annotation does not do the trick.
`nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing column [great_objectdao_id] in table [our_join_table]`

I suppose column name generation was always taking into consideration not a table name, but object name then. What's making things harder, is our scheme where we have a `BaseDAO` and `BaseObjectDAO` objects inside of which the `@OneToMany` relations exist.

`SomeOtherDAO` object would have a `some_other` table name.

```
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseDAO {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;
    (...)
}
```

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true, exclude = {"objectSources"})
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseObjectDAO extends BaseDAO {

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany
    private Set<SomeOtherDAO> objectSources;

    (........)
}
```

How do the objects extending `BaseObjectDAO` look like:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "great_object")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class GreatObjectDAO extends BaseObjectDAO {
```

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "strange_object")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class StrangeObjectDAO extends BaseObjectDAO {
```

**Question:**
How do we force it to generate join tables with column names `great_object_id` and `strange_object_id` instead of `great_objectdao_id` and `strange_objectdao_id`?

The great_object table should remain to have the `id` column, and the change should only be visible in the join table.

`join_table` table column names we have and want to keep:
`great_object_id`, `object_sources_id`

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `@AttributeOverride` annotation to change the name of the id column of the subclasses. See https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/AttributeOverride.html

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "great_object")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Accessors(chain = true)
@AttributeOverride(name="id", column=@Column(name="great_object_id"))
public class GreatObjectDAO extends BaseObjectDAO {
```

Comment: The problem is that the one to may association is defined in `MappedSuperclass` so we don't annotate it. Perhaps with using AssociationOverride: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/AssociationOverride.html